# Is this ODE solvable? I am struggling…

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This question may seem random…

I was wondering if one could solve.. $$e^x \int \sin (\ln y) \,dx=\int \cos (\ln y) \, dx$$

So I came up with the following equation and I am struggling with it.
$$y'(x)\bigg(e^x\cos\big(\log(y(x))\big) - 1\bigg) = y(x)\bigg(\big(-e^x - 1\big)\sin\big(\log(y(x))\big) - \cos\big(\log(y(x))\big)\bigg)$$

Comment: $\displaystyle cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$e^x \int \sin (\ln y) \,dx=\int \cos (\ln y) \, dx$$
Let :
$$z(x)=\ln(y(x))$$
$$e^x \int \sin (z) \,dx=\int \cos (z) \, dx$$
Differentiation :
$$e^x\sin(z)+e^x\int \sin (z) \,dx=\cos(z)$$
$$\sin(z)+\int \sin (z) \,dx=e^{-x}\cos(z)$$
Differentiation :
$$\cos(z)z'+\sin (z)=-e^{-x}\cos(z)-e^{-x}\sin(z)z'$$
$$\left(\cos(z)+e^{-x}\sin(z)\right)z'=-e^{-x}\cos(z)-\sin(z)$$
$$z'=-\frac{\cos(z)+\sin(z)e^x}{\sin(z)+\cos(z)e^x}$$
$$\boxed{z'=-\frac{1+e^x\tan(z)}{\tan(z)+e^x}}$$
Probably this nonlinear ODE cannot be solved analytically in terms of a finite number of standard functions. In practice, better use numerical methods of calculus to solve the problem.